# Dynamically generated Dropdown in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

How do we create a dropdown in google sheets based upon data in the next column -:

I search about it did not found a way that makes dropdown based upon a formula, I know about named ranges with which **I can create dependent dropdown**, but the problem is **my list dynamically generated so dropdown should be.**

Like in screenshot [image]

Link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BF0I3TACr1GJXmn1vse-tAE4b1h-yKp9SzGMfstVqbs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you need a script for that

Comment: Yes,I can do that with the script but I am trying to find a way to do with Functions.

Comment: this is just not possible to solve with formulas

Comment: Okay ,Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a DataValidation with the column to the right of active cell**

```
function createValidationWithNextColumn() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getActiveCell().clearDataValidations();//remove any current validations
  var rule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInRange(sh.getRange(sh.getActiveCell().getRow(),sh.getActiveCell().getColumn()+1,sh.getLastRow(),1))
  .build();
  sh.getActiveCell().setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

- [Data Validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)
- [ClearValidations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearDataValidations())
- [SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newDataValidation())
- [range.setDataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setDataValidation(DataValidation))